# NVIDIA hdmi output not working

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, graphics, hdmi, garuda-linux

I'm running Garuda linux on my desktop and my computer has 2 HDMI ports and one of those comes from the NVIDIA 2070 super. The regular HDMI works all the time with no issues but the nvidia one just seems to stop working with no errors or anything.

If the cable is plugged in on boot it will work if I'm in BIOS but after that the screen is frozen on the `welcome to grub` screen.

I'm guessing this is a problem with my nvidia drivers. How do I trouble shoot?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue on archlinux on my Ryzen 7 Omen 15, which has AMD Renoir integrated GPU with NVIDIA RTX 2060 discrete GPU:

**OS**: Arch Linux [x86_64]
**Host**: OMEN Laptop 15-en0xxx
**Kernel**: 5.17.5-arch1-1
**Resolution**: 2560x1440 @ 144Hz
**DE**: KDE Plasma 5.24.4
**WM**: KWin (X11)
**CPU**: AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 2.9GHz
**GPU 1**: AMD ATI Renoir
**GPU 2**: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060 Mobile

Monitor was not working, tried

```
nvidia-xconfig
```

Then the monitor worked but the display didn't work. Switched to another tty, and removed xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

to make it work again, but then again the monitor did not work.

Finally tried [optimus-manager](https://github.com/Askannz/optimus-manager), worked like a charm! Just follow the instructions on the github README, they're pretty good (So good that the arch wiki [points to them](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_Optimus#Using_optimus-manager))

Still, for completion, here's what I did:

1. Install optimus-manager using AUR
2. Ensure the xorg.conf generated by running nvidia-xconfig is removed & reboot
3. Install optimus-manager-qt (setting _with_plasma=true in the PKGBUILD as I'm using KDE Plasma)
4. Run optimus-manager-qt in terminal, select Nvidia GPU from the tray icon
5. It logs-out and logs back in and voila! Display on both built-in monitor & external monitor!

Now the built-in KDE display configurations on pressing the button on my laptop keyboard also work!